# store friendly-url with php in database created from db-field as source

Tags: php, store, friendly-url

Upfront, I have nearly no php coding skills, so please excuse if I am asking very basic questions.

I want to create a php file I can execute via cron job which creates friendly_URLs in a non-modx-database. I have a table "myuri" which has 3 columns "id" "title" "uri" (uri is default NULL)

Here is what the script should do

- connect to the db-server
- select the db
- Update all "uri"-fields that are NULL with a friendly URL created
  from each title in the corresponding "title"-field

With my very basic understanding of what I am doing, I only managed to glue some code snipped mixture of php and xPDO together that is doing something, but not exaxtly what I need.

What I have sofar is a mix of modx xPDO and SQL

```
// [PHP/SQL] db connect
mysql_connect("hostname", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("database");

// [xPDO] path
define('MODX_CORE_PATH', '/website/domain.tld/core/');
define('MODX_CONFIG_KEY','config');
require_once MODX_CORE_PATH . 'model/modx/modx.class.php';

// [xPDO] Criteria for foreign Database
$host = 'hostname';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'password';
$dbname = 'database';
$port = 3306;
$charset = 'utf-8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;port=$port;charset=$charset";
$xpdo = new xPDO($dsn, $username, $password);

// [PHP/SQL] Function that removes all unfriendly signs from the title example: "Hello! World" to "hello-world"
function Slug($string)
{
return strtolower(trim(preg_replace('~[^0-9a-z]+~i', '-', html_entity_decode(preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), '-'));
}

// [xPDO] Issue queries against the foreign database, for testing limited to a few ids instead of "WHERE id is null"
$output = '';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myuri WHERE id BETWEEN 564780000 AND 564781000";
foreach ($xpdo->query($sql) as $row) {
$output .= $row['title'];
}

// [PHP/SQL] take the xPDO query results and run "function Slug($string)" on it (i guess this needs to go into the "foreach" somehow)
$user = $output;
$item = "test-parent-folder/".Slug($user).".html";

// [PHP/SQL] Update the column "uri", for testing limited to a few ids instead of "WHERE id is null" (this needs to go into the "foreach" too)
mysql_query("UPDATE myuri SET uri = '$item' id BETWEEN 564780000 AND 564781000");
```

So basically I need to do two major things.

1.) Replace all [xPDO] components with [PHP/SQL] components to be able to run it as a cron job

2.) Include the things into the for each function, here is were my php skill hits its limits

3.)(optional) From what I have read in some postings it might be clever to run this with an "implode" for make it run faster since the table has 1.000.000 rows

Would be great if anybody could help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick note,

```
mysql_query("UPDATE myuri SET uri = '$item' id BETWEEN 564780000 AND 564781000");
```

Will not do what you want I guess, this function will overwrite like all values between 5647800000 and 564781000 by one single new value. In the code below I have fixed this, like you want (probably, this is how URL shortners work)

```
<?php
define('MODX_CORE_PATH', '/website/domain.tld/core/');
define('MODX_CONFIG_KEY','config');
require_once MODX_CORE_PATH . 'model/modx/modx.class.php';
//FILL THIS IN//
$host = 'hostname';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'password';
$dbname = 'database';
$port = 3306;
$charset = 'utf-8';

//DON'T CHANGE BELOW//
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($dbname);

// [PHP/SQL] Function that removes all unfriendly signs from the title example: "Hello! World" to "hello-world"
function Slug($string)
{
return strtolower(trim(preg_replace('~[^0-9a-z]+~i', '-', html_entity_decode(preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), '-'));
}

$items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myuri WHERE id BETWEEN 564780000 AND 564781000");
while($item = mysql_fetch_object($items)) {
mysql_query("UPDATE myuri SET uri='test-parent-folder/".Slug($item->title).".html' WHERE id='".$item->id."'");
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for taking the time to help me.

Comment: I get the following error:... Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array on line 23 ... This line is.. while($item = mysql_fetch_object($items)) { ... since I removed the first 3 lines which are no longer required.

Comment: its getting closer :) ... I replaced: $items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myuri WHERE id BETWEEN 564780000 AND 564781000"); ... with: $items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myuri WHERE uri is null"); ... since I want to write the created URL in all fields of the column "uri" where currently is no entry.

Comment: But the function Slug($string) is not working properly yet. In the current state the script writes "test-parent-folder/.html" in all "uri" fields. But it should also add the Value for .Slug($user) . So an example: If in one row in the column "title" is written "Hello!?! World" ... this script should write "test-parent-folder/hello-world.html" in the column "uri" of this row.

Comment: ok I got it:replace  ... Slug($user) ... with:... Slug($item->title) ... thank you very very much again for your help! you made my day :)